# How to create Datasource through AWS Machine Learning SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a Datasource using AWS Machine learning SDK. I have a data set and its corresponding schema.Both are stored in S3.Initially i thought that i just need to provide column names in schema. so initially my schema looked like this -

```
ColName1,ColName2,....,ColNameN
```

Later i realized that i need to put the datatype into the schema not label names.so i changed my schema to

```
Number, String,....,String
```

Still i am not able to create datasource because of improper schema. I am getting this error -

```
FAILURES (1): There was an error trying to parse the schema: 'Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3ef68a3a; line: 1, column: 2]'
```

Now i think that i need to provide the schema in json format, though i am not sure,can someone please provide example of what to put in schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filename- dataset.schema (it is mandatory to have **.schema** as extension of schema file)

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "targetAttributeName": "A5",
    "dataFormat": "CSV",
    "dataFileContainsHeader": false,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "attributeName": "A1",
            "attributeType": "TEXT"
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "A2",
            "attributeType": "NUMERIC"
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "A3",
            "attributeType": "CATEGORICAL"
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "A4",
            "attributeType": "TEXT"
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "A5",
            "attributeType": "BINARY"
        }
      ]  
    }
```